# Expansion of \newcommand

Tags: macros, footnotes

The problem I am having is certainly due to my lack of understanding regarding the details of how `\newcommand`, `\def`, `\edef`, `\let`, etc. work, though I happened to encounter the problem when making use of the `fnpct` package.

Below is a MWE with output (the actual footnote has been suppressed to save space).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fnpct}

\newcommand{\comma}{,}

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{This is a footnote}, World!

Hello\footnote{This is another footnote}\comma again!

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

The objective is to have both cases produce the same output (well, the output of the footnote and comma anyways).  (For reasons that are not given in the MWE, not making use of the `\comma` command is not an option.)

My understanding is that the `fnpct` package redefines the `\footnote` command to read-in what immediately follows the footnote and to type-set accordingly.  In the second case, it seems as if it will read-in `\comma` instead of `,`, and so does not properly change how it type-sets.  Is there a way I can define a `\comma` command so that it just replaces all instances of `\comma` with `,` before 'actual' compile-time?  (I have in mind something similar to the `#define` compiler directive in C.)  Or perhaps there is some other way to accomplish the desired result?

**Update**:  Changing `\newcommand{\comma}{,}` to `\newcommand{\comma}{,\ }` and adding the line `\setfnpct{add-punct-marks=\comma}` immediately after `\begin{document}` as suggested by clemens yields the following output.  This fixes the order of the comma and the footnote, but there is still the issue of the order of the space and the footnote.

[image: MWE2]

Comment: `\setfnpct{add-punct-marks = \comma}` should work as far as `fnpct` is concerned. The fact that there is no space after `\comma` unlike after `,` is another matter

Comment: @clemens Yes, I probably should have written `\newcommand{\comma}{,\ }` in the MWE as this is what I need in practice.  With this together with `\setfnpct{add-punct-marks=\comma}` unfortunately does not achieved the desired result, as you say.

Comment: Yes, that would be more or less the same as if you wrote `\comma\footnote{...}` in the first place…

Comment: But that is not at all what you need in practice. If you define `\comma` in that way then of course you will get the output you posted because that is just what you told `fnpct` you wanted i.e. `,\ ` to be treated as punctuation it should shift to the left of a footnote. What you want is just the `,` shifted. The space you want after the footnote marker. You just need to protect this space as is usual with macros e.g. `\footnote{note}\comma{} but...` or whatever.  Of course, you must remember this every time you use `\comma`. (But writing `,` is so much saner anyway, this is a minor point.)

Comment: Note that your C example is leading you astray, TeX is a macro expansion language not a compiler, so the analogy is _only_ having  `#define` .

Comment: @cfr just noticed my answer is a copy of your comment, sorry:-) made mine cw

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No worries. My comment is a converted would-be answer which I didn't post because I realised that clemens had made the crucial point and only the bit about this-is-just-what-always-happens-with-macros was additional.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

In `\comma again` the space is never tokenized it is simply absorbed as the terminator for the command name, if it was not there the input would be `\commaagain` and refer to the undefined command `commaagain`.  This is nothing to do with comma, but just TeX syntax.

The solution is not (for many reasons) to put a space into the definition of `\comma` as usually it will put space in unwanted places as you show. It is better to correct the markup so that a space token is added at the point you want a space, so `\comma{} again` here.

With the correct input syntax, the declaration [clemens suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276444/expansion-of-newcommand?noredirect=1#comment665467_276444) produces the above output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fnpct}

\newcommand{\comma}{,}
\setfnpct{add-punct-marks=\comma}

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{This is a footnote}, World!

Hello\footnote{This is another footnote}\comma{} again!

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is clemens suggesting the syntax - not the OP.

Comment: @cfr it's cw you can edit it,  I'm giving up for the night:-)